# Undefined reference to CMU Sphinx functions in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt5, cmusphinx

I'm trying to use CMU Sphinx in Qt. I've installed pocketsphinx and sphinxbase, and made a project in Qt, and added the following code to the `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <pocketsphinx.h>
#define MODELDIR "/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ps_decoder_t *ps = nullptr;
    cmd_ln_t *config = nullptr;
    config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
                         "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
                         "-lm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us.lm.bin",
                         "-dict", MODELDIR "/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
                         NULL);
}
```

I've also added the following lines to the `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/sphinxbase
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/pocketsphinx
```

When I try building, I get the following errors:

- undefined reference to `ps_args`
- undefined reference to `cmd_ln_init`

I'm on Debian 8. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this might seem silly, but I finally solved the issue, and I hope this helps anyone with similar errors in Qt in the future.

The way to solve it is to right-click anywhere in the editor, and click Add Library, and then select System Library. I then entered the library name, which in my case was `pocketsphinx`. I repeated it for `sphinxbase`. Then go to Build - Run qmake, and then build.